# Translate rvt to dwg job progress remains 0%

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I wanted to convert the Revit file sheet to DWG file, so
I created a job using the Model Derivative API,
When I check the Manifest, Progress will remain at 0% no matter how many hours have passed.

The following json was used to create the job

```
{
  "input" : {
    "urn" : "dXJuOmFk****************************QucnZ0"
  },
  "output" : {
    "formats" : [
      {
        "type" : "dwg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The result of getManifest is as follows.

```
Autodesk\Forge\Client\Model\Manifest Object (
    [container:protected] => Array (
        [urn] => dXJuOmFk****************************QucnZ0
        [type] => manifest
        [progress] => 0% complete
        [status] => success
        [has_thumbnail] => 1
        [region] => US
        [derivatives] => Array ( )
    )
)
```

Uses PHP Forge-sdk

What can I do to make the translation progress?

Comment: can you share the URN? (this is not confidential)

Comment: Can you send the drawing via GDrive/weTransfer/Dropbox to forge.help@autodesk.com if possible so we can investigate? This might have to do with a known issue that our Engineering team is looking into where the extractor would time out due to certain particulars of the drawing.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Because this file is confidential,
I will send the file to forge.help email address.

Comment: @XCoder I'm having the same issue, were you able to make this work? I'm trying to use one of the sample files from the Autodesk website and it's not working.

Comment: @RaúlBojalil
In my case, I didn't have a public setting in 2D view.
It seems that only publicly set views are subject to conversion.